# Hide a custom input form

Tags: c#

I have three forms in my application.

Form1 is the main form.
Form2 is a form with two input fields.
Form3 is a password verification form which is triggered from Form1 and upon successful authentication, Form2 is shown.

Form1 -> Form3 -> Form2

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.textBox_entry_password.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a password", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                        MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
        this.textBox_entry_password.Focus();
    }

    else
    {
        // Authentication not Implemented so far
        Form Form2 = new Form2();
        Form2.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

        // Code for hiding Form3 -- Needed ????
        Form2.ShowDialog();
    }
```

I want Form1 to stay as such and hide Form3 and show Form2.

```
this.hide()
```

hides Form1.

If i try

```
Form Form3 = new Form3();
Form3.Hide();
```

It does nothing. Form3 stays right there.

How do i hide Form3?

Comment: In your code you don't actually *show* an instance of `Form3`.  You create a new instance and immediately try to hide it.  Wherever you're creating the instance of `Form3` that gets shown, that's the instance you need to hide.

Comment: This button1_Click() is called from Form3. I am already on Form3. Form1 is also visible. What i want is only to hide the existing instance of Form3 and show Form2 while Form1 stays there.

Comment: In Form1 you hide Form1 and then start Form2. In Form2 you hide Form2 and start Form3. In Form3 you hide Form3 etc.

Login form -> Main form would actually be enough in your case. You should consider naming your forms as well for readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
  Form2 a = new Form2 ();
     a.Show();
     this.Close();
```

in the button click event inside `Form3`

Comment: This code hides Form3 but it shows some unusual behavior. It hides the Form2 to taskbar and you have to click on it to bring it to focus. I tried the focus() and WindowState but no luck.

Comment: do the same snippet When you pass from form1 --> form3 ie like this `Form3 a = new Form3 ();
     a.Show();
     this.Close();` in the event click inside form1

Comment: It works OK. But creates another problem. When passing form1 --> form3, using this.Close(); tries to close the Main Form which is Form1.

Comment: Commenting out `this.Close()` solves the focus problem but Form3 remains visible behind Form2. @majid-khan you asked for help with _hiding_ Form3.

Comment: Also Form2 is shown modelessly by `a.Show()`, so the user can move it aside and use Form3 again. Is this the behaviour you want?

Comment: If i want to change it to modal dialog, i have to use ShowDialog() property. Hope that won't create a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create an overload of your `Form3()` constructor and pass `Form1` instance to it.

```
private Form form;
public Form3(Form frm)
{
  form = frm;
}
```

Now wherever you want to hide/show form1, just use `form.Hide(), form.Show();`

In your case use

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.textBox_entry_password.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a password", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
            this.textBox_entry_password.Focus();
        }

        else
        {

            // Authentication not Implemented so far

            Form Form2 = new Form2();
            Form2.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

            // Code for hiding Form3 -- Needed ????
            Form2.ShowDialog();
            this.Hide();
            form.ShowDialog();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ther are many ways to do this. Below is an approach that I like because the password form is only concerned with obtaining and authenticating a password, and knows nothing about Form1 and Form2.

Code in Form3:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.textBox_entry_password.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a password", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
        this.textBox_entry_password.Focus();
    }
    else
    {
        // Authentication code here
        // if (isAuthenticated)
        // {
        //     DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        //     Close(); // hides and closes the form
        // }
     }
}
```

Code in Form1, to use Form 3 and Form2:

```
var dialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;

// Always explicitly dispose a form shown modally; using clause will do this.
using (var form3 = new Form3())
{
    dialogResult = form3.ShowDialog(this);
}

if (dialogResult == DialogResult.OK) // password authenticated
{
    // Always explicitly dispose a form shown modally; using clause will do this.
    using (var form2 = new Form2())
    {
        dialogResult = form2.ShowDialog(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do i use this code in Form1? I put the other in Form3. Form3 takes the password input and closes.

Comment: Use this code in Form1 wherever you want to show Form3 and Form2. Do you not already have code in Form1 to show Form3 and Form2?