# Opening new Windows Form from another Form

Tags: c#, forms, host

Now before anyone goes and marks this question as a duplicate, I'd like to say that my problem differs from the other ones. I'm trying to open an existing Form from another, but I'm having problems in the sense that I've set some Forms to 'host' others (To transfer variables between them). Here's what I mean:

```
 public partial class Schedule_Tasks : Form
{

    readonly Schedules schedules;

    public Schedule_Tasks(Schedules host)
    {
        this.schedules = host;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

So in this snippet of code, I'm trying to get the value of some variables from the Schedules form, into the Schedule_Tasks Form. So I've used the 'host' system. SO far this method works fine, but my problem occurs when I try to open a specific Form, from another that isn't 'hosting'. For example using:

```
new Schedules().Show();
```

So obviously when I'm declaring this, I'd put something like 'this' in the brackets after Schedules, but that doesn't work if the Form is being called outside of the 'host' Form. I'd just like to now is there something I'm missing or can change? Please let me know if any part isn't clear, it's a little difficult to explain. Any help is appreciated, Cheers.

**EDIT**

Here's the code that I'm working with now:

```
 public partial class Schedual_Tasks : Form
{



    readonly Scheduals scheduals;
    public string selectedDevice;
    public string getPath;
    public string totalPath;


    public Schedual_Tasks(Scheduals host)
    {
        this.scheduals = host;
        InitializeComponent();
        selectedDevice = scheduals.itemSelected;
    }

    private void Schedual_Tasks_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void changeDirectory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Folder_Browser(this).Show(); //Error Occurs here
    }
}
```

And here is the constructor for Folder_Browser, which is the Form I'm trying to call:

```
 readonly Back_up_Options backOptions;
    public string deviceSel;

    public Folder_Browser(Back_up_Options host)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.backOptions = host;
        deviceSel = backOptions.deviceSel;

    }
```

Comment: I think you cannot `new Schedules().Show();` you could call the object method after instantiated say `myForm = new Schedules();` `myForm.Show();` But I want don't know yet what do you meant by `"Form, from another that isn't hosting"`? It's better to put most if not ALL of your code here so that we could see the whole picture.

Comment: Schedules is also a `Form`, right? When you speak about a problem that occurs, what is the problem? Compile-time error or runtime exception?

Comment: `schedules.Show()` doesn't work?

Comment: will you please put some more code so that we can get some idea what is the actual problem ..

Comment: @Edper I've added the code I'm working with. What I meant with that is I've just got elements from another form in the one that's being 'hosted', I don't know a better way of putting that.

Comment: The form which needs to be shown again can always be hidden and shown again .. is it really necessary in your flow to close and reopen the form ?? P.S to avoid multiple instances of the form you may have to use Singleton approach..

Comment: @OndrejJanacek That is correct, I get an error when declaring the new form: Best overloaded method match for *some form* has some invalid arguments

Comment: @Deadlock I've the function I'm working with

Comment: @Rafay My problem is actually showing a completely new form, but I can't seem to find an error free way of doing that with the current method I'm using

Comment: @VanMan what is `Back_up_Options` class?

Comment: @Grundy So it's another 'parent' or 'hosting' class, I have a few classes kind of inheriting elements of each other through their constructors

Comment: @VanMan In that case I would recommend to use a Global Class .. P.S a [Sample](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19792054/setting-string-to-public-c-sharp-web-developer/19792179?noredirect=1#comment29423370_19792179)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide a custom input form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19597433/hide-a-custom-input-form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your (`Folder_Browser`) Form's constructor is declared as

```
public Folder_Browser(Back_up_Options host)
```

That means you cannot pass a `Schedual_Tasks` instance as the `host` parameter because there is no way to convert from a `Schedual_Tasks` object into a `Back_up_Options` object. The compiler detects this and creates an error message.

If you cannot pass the `host` parameter, you can pass `null` instead:

```
new Folder_Browser(null).Show();
```

But then you need to make sure that you **check** the `backOptions` member for **null reference each time you use it**. For example:

```
if(backOptions != null)
{
    deviceSel = backOptions.deviceSel;
}
else 
{
    deviceSel = null;
}
```

That in turn means that you will need to check `deviceSel` for null each time you use it and so on.

And of course, using your Form without a "host" needs to be possible at all. If you have code that **requires** a "host", it will fail.